# Qt LocalStorage foreign keys in Qml

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, qml

I'm using qt LocalStorage in Qml project with Sqlite db.
I noticed that the foreign keys do not work and I cannot get them activated:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
        tx.executeSql('delete from Panels where id = ?',
                      [panelId])
    })
```

does not work.
Anyone knows how to do with the LocalStorage?

Comment: As I see your query doesn't contain foreign key

Comment: It's in a related table CONSTRAINT AntibioticsPanels_Panels_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_panel) REFERENCES Panels (id)

Comment: Ok, perhaps related table has value with this `panelID` and so data integrity doesn't allow you to delete this data. What error do you get?

Comment: No error. That is the question. It lets me delete data

Comment: @folibis you know what I have to do? thx